# keras. Initializing a bidirecional LSTM. Passing word embeddings

Tags: python, keras, lstm, embedding

In the implementation i am using, the lstm is initialized in the following way:

```
l_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))(embedded_sequences)
```

What i don't really understand and it might be because of the lack of experience in Python generally: the notation `l_lstm= Bidirectional(LSTM(...))(embedded_sequences)`. 
I don't get what i am passing the `embedded_sequences` to? Because it is not a parameter of `LSTM()` but also does not seem to be an argument for `Bidirectional()` as it stands separately.

Here is the documentation for Bidirectional:

```
  def __init__(self, layer, merge_mode='concat', weights=None, **kwargs):
        if merge_mode not in ['sum', 'mul', 'ave', 'concat', None]:
            raise ValueError('Invalid merge mode. '
                             'Merge mode should be one of '
                             '{"sum", "mul", "ave", "concat", None}')
        self.forward_layer = copy.copy(layer)
        config = layer.get_config()
        config['go_backwards'] = not config['go_backwards']
        self.backward_layer = layer.__class__.from_config(config)
        self.forward_layer.name = 'forward_' + self.forward_layer.name
        self.backward_layer.name = 'backward_' + self.backward_layer.name
        self.merge_mode = merge_mode
        if weights:
            nw = len(weights)
            self.forward_layer.initial_weights = weights[:nw // 2]
            self.backward_layer.initial_weights = weights[nw // 2:]
        self.stateful = layer.stateful
        self.return_sequences = layer.return_sequences
        self.return_state = layer.return_state
        self.supports_masking = True
        self._trainable = True
        super(Bidirectional, self).__init__(layer, **kwargs)
        self.input_spec = layer.input_spec
        self._num_constants = None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to break down what is going on:

1. You start with `LSTM(...)` which creates an LSTM *Layer*. Now [layers in Keras are callable](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) which means you can use them like functions. For example `lstm = LSTM(...)` and then `lstm(some_input)` will *call* the LSTM on the given input tensor.
2. The `Bidirectional(...)` *wraps* any RNN layer and returns you *another layer* that when called applies the wrapped layer in both directions. So `l_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(...))` is a layer when called with some input will apply the `LSTM` in both direction. *Note:* Bidirectional creates a copy of passed LSTM layer, so backwards and forwards are different LSTMs.
3. Finally, when you call `Bidirectional(LSTM(...))(embedded_seqences)` bidirectional layer takes the input sequences, passes it to the wrapped LSTMs in both directions, collects their output and concatenates it.

To understand more about layers and their callable nature, you can look at the [functional API guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) of the documentation.